# Error when joining multiple times the same table

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter, activerecord

Is it possible to join multiple tables while working more than once with one table ? Let me explain.

I have three tables `categories`, `content` and `members`. 
Using CodeIgniter's ActiveRecord btw. Here is my `content_model.php`:

```
public function get_content_list(){

    $this->db
        ->select('
            content.id,
            categories.id as catid,
            categories.title as category,
            content.alvl,
            content.ordering,
            content.state,
            content.title,
            content.slug,
            content.text,
            content.views,
            content.aid,
            members.username as author,
        ')
        ->join('categories', 'content.catid = categories.id')
        ->join('categories', 'content.alvl = categories.id') // MARK01
        ->join('members', 'content.aid = members.id');

    $query = $this->db->get($this->_table_name);

    if($query->num_rows() > 0)
        return $query->result();
    else
        return FALSE;

}
```

I left a 2nd line commented as **MARK01**, that's where the problem is started.

Now to clarify, the *categories* are stored in one DB table `categories` for `members`, `contents` (pages, articles, etc.), `banners` and so on... There is a column `categories.cid` which stands for *Component's ID* and is connected to DB table `components`. So whenever i need to retrieve a categories for lets say members, I'll use `WHERE` `categories.cid = 3`. It works fine, until that point where I need to retrieve JOINed records from multiple tables while interrogating the same table more than once.

This is a `var_dump()` with commented lines to explain, with COMMENTED the **MARK01** line to prevent ERROR:

```
array (size=3)
  0 => 
    object(stdClass)[41]
      public 'id' => string '1' (length=1)
      public 'catid' => string '5' (length=1)
      public 'category' => string 'News' (length=4)
      public 'alvl' => string '10' (length=2) // Access level
      public 'ordering' => string '1' (length=1)
      public 'state' => string '1' (length=1) // Status ON/OFF
      public 'title' => string 'Qualification for a new production set' (length=38)
      public 'slug' => string 'qualification-for-a-new-production-set' (length=38)
      public 'text' => string 'Very long text blablabla"'... (length=2629)
      public 'views' => string '13' (length=3)
      public 'aid' => string '1' (length=1)  // Author ID
      public 'author' => string 'aspirinemaga' (length=12)
```

And this is what I get when uncommenting the 2nd line **MARK01**:

```
A Database Error Occurred
Error Number: 1066
Not unique table/alias: 'cis_categories'
SELECT `cis_content`.`id`, `cis_categories`.`id` as catid, `cis_categories`.`title` as category, `cis_content`.`alvl`, `cis_content`.`ordering`, `cis_content`.`state`, `cis_content`.`title`, `cis_content`.`slug`, `cis_content`.`text`, `cis_content`.`views`, `cis_content`.`aid`, `cis_members`.`username` as author FROM (`cis_content`) JOIN `cis_categories` ON `cis_content`.`catid` = `cis_categories`.`id` JOIN `cis_categories` ON `cis_content`.`alvl` = `cis_categories`.`id` JOIN `cis_members` ON `cis_content`.`aid` = `cis_members`.`id`
Filename: D:\wamp\www\cmstut\system\database\DB_driver.php
Line Number: 330
```

Any idea what's wrong here ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you JOIN table more than 1 time, you have to give them different names.

```
... JOIN categories categories2 ON content.catid = categories2.id...
```

In this case you should use "categories2" to define "ON". For the "SELECT" also use your new name

For the codeigniter active record you can try

```
$this->db->join('categories AS categories2',...)
```

Comment: For the codeigniter active record you can try $this->db->join('categories AS categories2',...)

Comment: would be nice if you'll update your answer with your comment also.